# Tensorflow.js GraphModel contains a node with dynamic op, so model.predict cannot be used

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow.js

I am using Tensorflow.js in a React Native app. I load an LSTM model just fine, but when I try to do model.predict(), I get the following error:

> Error: This execution contains the node
> 'StatefulPartitionedCall/model/bidirectional_2/forward_lstm_2/PartitionedCall/while/exit/_370',
> which has the dynamic op 'Exit'. Please use model.executeAsync()
> instead. Alternatively, to avoid the dynamic ops, specify the inputs
> [StatefulPartitionedCall/model/bidirectional_2/forward_lstm_2/PartitionedCall/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack]

I didn't know what specifying the inputs meant, so I asked chatGPT, which told me to do `model.predict({'StatefulPartitionedCall/model/bidirectional_2/forward_lstm_2/PartitionedCall/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack':input);`

I tried this, and it gave me the same error except with backward_lstm_2 instead of forward_lstm_2, so I changed it to `model.predict({'StatefulPartitionedCall/model/bidirectional_2/forward_lstm_2/PartitionedCall/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack':input, 'StatefulPartitionedCall/model/bidirectional_2/backward_lstm_2/PartitionedCall/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack':input};`

This then resolved the previous errors, but gave me this new error:

> Error in matMul: inner shapes (12) and (256) of Tensors with shapes
> 3,12 and 256,149 and transposeA=false and transposeB=false must match.

I know that the input shape of the LSTM layer is 256, which is probably the reason for this.
I do not understand what the original error message of "specify the inputs" refers to, and when I tried to use executeAsync, the output was something like this: {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}.

Can someone help me please? Thanks.